# How to use dsfonts and kpfonts together?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm getting the error "Too many math alphabets used in normal mode" when using these two packages simultaneously.

I looked for solutions on the internet relating to this error but they are not specifically for this problem. As far as I understand, some alphabet definitions clash in these two packages.

Since I'm only using `\mathds{1}`, is there a way to define this double strike 1 without including `dsfonts`?  Also, please avoid using the XeLaTeX compilation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

```
\newcommand{\dsone}{\text{\usefont{U}{dsrom}{m}{n}1}}
```

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\newcommand{\dsone}{\text{\usefont{U}{dsrom}{m}{n}1}}

\begin{document}

\[
a+b-\dsone \qquad X_{\dsone}
\]

\end{document}
```

Don't forget the braces around the subscript.

How do I know the correct font? The code of `dsfont.sty` is

```
\def\ds@whichfont{dsrom}
\DeclareOption{sans}{\def\ds@whichfont{dsss}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathds}{U}{\ds@whichfont}{m}{n}
```

so the font used for `\mathds` is `\U/dsrom/m/n`. If you want the sans serif version, replace `dsrom` with `dsss`.

[image]